# Why subsequent Temporary table creation throws error while using Statement with DBCP2?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, apache-commons-dbcp, mssql-jdbc

I am trying to create a Temporary table - `#EMPLOYEE_TABLE` on MSSQL database using Spring and DBCP2 connection pooling. I am using `java.sql.Statement` to perform execute on the DB. I close the connection after the execute, to send it back to the connection pool. This creation process works fine for the first execute. But for the subsequent execution, it throws the following error:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: There is already an object named '#EMPLOYEE_TABLE' in the database.12:26:37.852 [34mINFO [0;39m [35mcom.lex.dbcp.dao.TestDaoImpl[0;39m - Connection :>>org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper@1807f5a7 
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:215)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1635)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.doExecuteStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:865)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement$StmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerStatement.java:762)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5846)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1719)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:184)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:159)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.execute(SQLServerStatement.java:735)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingStatement.execute(DelegatingStatement.java:175)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingStatement.execute(DelegatingStatement.java:175)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingStatement.execute(DelegatingStatement.java:175)
    at com.lex.dbcp.dao.TestDaoImpl.createTempTableUsingStatement(TestDaoImpl.java:131)
    at com.lex.dbcp.common.App.main(App.java:25)
```

It is a MSSQL 2014 DB and the DBCP2 version is 2.6.0 and I am running this on java 1.8

However, if I change the execute implementation from `java.sql.Statement` to `java.sql.PreparedStatement`, the execution work fine for any number of firings.

Sample code for using the Statement interface:

```
    public void createTempTableUsingStatement() {

        Connection conn = null;
        Statement st = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        String sqlQuery = "SELECT * INTO #EMPLOYEE_TABLE FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE 1=2";

        try {
            conn = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();

            st = conn.createStatement();
            st.execute(sqlQuery);

            LOGGER.info("Table created");

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

            if (null != st) {
                try {
                    st.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (null != rs) {
                try {
                    rs.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if (null != conn) {
                try {
                    conn.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Sample code using PreparedStatement

```
public void createTempTableUsingPreparedStatement() {

        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        String sqlQuery = "SELECT * INTO #EMPLOYEE_TABLE FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE 1=2";

        try {
            conn = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();

            ps = conn.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
            ps.execute();

            LOGGER.info("Table created");

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

            if (null != ps) {
                try {
                    ps.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (null != rs) {
                try {
                    rs.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if (null != conn) {
                try {
                    conn.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Table structure

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE(
                emp_id int identity,
                emp_name varchar(255)
);
```

I have left a copy of the source project for reference here [StandAlone](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AuCZYE5iPBw80022-oKJHFVVn4Ts)

Now what I would like to understand is that, why does the temporary table creation for multiple firing work in case of `java.sql.PreparedStatement` and not in case of `java.sql.Statement`. I have used `try with resources` as well to see if it was problem in release of resources and got the same result.

Am I missing out something? Can someone please help me understand this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

When you use a connection pool, the connection can be reused for a different request. SQL Server local temporary tables are valid for the lifetime of a session. Unless specific action is taken, that is calling `sp_reset_connection`, the length of a session is equal to the lifetime of the connection. In that situation, the lifetime of a temporary table is the lifetime of a connection.

DBCP doesn't know anything about the particulars of SQL Server, so it doesn't know it should call `sp_reset_connection` to start a new session on an existing connection. As `sp_reset_connection` isn't called, the local temporary tables will continue to exist until explicitly dropped or the connection is closed.

You either need to drop the temporary table when you are done, conditionally drop before creating, or only create when the table doesn't exist yet.

Alternatively, you need to make sure that DBCP will execute `sp_reset_connection` before handing out the connection. It might be possible to use (or abuse) the `validationQuery` with `testOnReturn` or `testOnBorrow`. I don't normally use DBCP nor SQL Server, so I can't give a working solution how, but you will need to fulfill the requirement that the validation query behaves as a select (ie: returns on or more rows, no update counts).

Comment: Thanks for your inputs Mark. `sp_reset_connection`  is indeed not called by any JDBC driver while returning the connection to the pool. An explicit call might be required in this case. But what I do not understand is, how does the scenario work when I use `java.sql.PreparedStatement` and not while using `java.sql.Statement`. It is as if `java.sql.PreparedStatement.close()` does a reset of the connection, while `java.sql.Statement.close()` doesnt. Strange.

Comment: @Niranjan I had ignored that part of your question, as I don't know why that difference exists. If I had to theorize, I'd say that maybe the prepare phase recognizes that the table already exists and reuses it, while a statement execute doesn't? I just don't know.

Comment: Did some analysis and found that I had missed the part that the using `java.sql.PreparedStatement` never created the Temporary table on the DB in the first place. No errors were thrown though. Weird. Made a change in approach for using `java.sql.Statement`, gonna try with a change in query `IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#EMPLOYEE_TABLE') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #EMPLOYEE_TABLE; SELECT * INTO #EMPLOYEE_TABLE FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE 1=2`. Will test how it goes. Thanks for the help again.